# What is Pitriloka (Pitṛloka)?

Tags: death, afterlife

What is pitṛloka? In many Hindu rituals (such as nandishraddha) pitṛs are invited from pitṛloka. I know that pitṛs are ancestors. But I want to know, where is the pitṛloka? Is it a sort of heaven? A stratum of heaven (svargoloka)? What is the difference between devaloka and pitṛloka? After death, some persons go to devaloka, some goes to pitṛloka. What decides that? If ancestors live in pitṛloka, then who reincarnates?

Answer (score 1):

Pitṛloka is known as the “world of ancestors” and it is the place where the subtle body travels to after death, according to V. Ravi in his [“Garuḍa Purāṇa Series”](https://manblunder.com/articlesview/garuda-purana-and-gayatri-mantra)

> Immediately after death, the subtle body leaves the gross body and enters the cosmos.  Next, the subtle body attains ghost hood and **at the end of a year, the subtle body joins the world of ancestors known as pitṛ loka**. Generally the world consists of many triads such as Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Śiva.  Brahmā presides over the portion from foot to navel; Viṣṇu presides over the portion from navel to neck and Śiva presides over the head of a human body.  They are only manifestations of the Brahman. [...]

As to it's location, Pitṛloka is stated to be between Bhūmaṇḍala and Garbhodaka according to Anju Misra is his article ["The Cosmography of the Purāṇas"](https://books.google.com/books?id=22KSEAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=bh%C5%ABma%E1%B9%87%E1%B8%8Dala&f=false)

> The firmament (Bhūmaṇḍala) is a thick circular disk that contains the earthly oceans and continents on its surface, and the seven netherworlds below it inhabited by different races of demon-gods, serpents, and natural spirits. 3 The region under the Bhūmaṇḍala is believed to be filled with the waters of the Garbhodaka ocean, a wave-less continuum of primordial matter from which all things emerge upon creation and into which all things return upon dissolution. **The realm of the forefathers (Pitṛloka)** and the various kinds of hells (Naraka or Yamaloka) are **located in the region between the Bhūmaṇḍala and the Garbhodaka ocean**. The entire universe is thought to be encircled by the endless coils of the cosmic-serpent Ananta Śeṣa who rests at the bottom of the Garbhodaka ocean (at a distance of 100,000 yojanas from the Bhūmaṇḍala).

Regarding the different realms or destinations after death, see the following excerpt based on Sri Sridhara Swami’s [commentary on Bhagavad Gita 9.25](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-9-25/)

> Now Lord Krishna explains the destinations of worship according to the desires of the particular worshippers. Those who worship the demigods like Indra the raingod and Surya the sungod go to Swargaloka the heavenly planets. **Those who perform sraddha or worship of the manes or ancestors go to Pitriloka** the planet of the forefathers. Those who worship the spirits and the female demigods go to the realm of the spirit. But the devotees of the Supreme Lord Krishna or any of His authorised incarnations and expansions as revealed in Vedic scriptures attain Him and the eternal spiritual worlds never to be born again.

It is my opinion that for a complete understanding of this information, you should take into consideration the context and details of the text found in the sources.

Answer (score 0):

```
           SINS & VIRTUES
```

PITRU LOKA is one step below SWARGA LOKA or NARAKA LOKA of clearly defined LOKAAs.

NARAKA LOKA for sinners and SWARGA LOKA for virtues.

PITRU LOKA is intermediate one where souls though eliminated from body may not attain peace, but they cant return to Earth where they had suffered lot from birth to death. If they had enjoyed from birth to death, also, the products (offsprings created by them - sons/ daughters) in Earth decide their state towards 2 lokaas (SWARGA & NARAKA).

Hence to liberate such souls towards PARAMAPATHANAATHA there is an option called PITRU LOKA.

```
        FAMILY FATHERS
```

SECRETS ABOUT PITRU LOKA are never revealed in Hinduism but we just follow KAARYA KRAMAAS as rituals. (SOULS - AATMASHAKTHI is very powerful). Other religions never believe that souls leave body and they preserve bodies on Earth for long time.

A big answer to above is Pitru loka. Soul is not fond of its own body after death.

```
  RETURNING FATHERS & MOTHERS
```

It is also feared that messengers of God on Earth from various religions in respective places were from Pitru lokaa (Jeyshu, Messiah, Nabi ,  Mahaaveera , Guru Nanak Sahib , Buddha , AathiVanShatagopan (human forms) Mermaids(feminine & other beings)) etc are from Pitru lokaa to make humans on Earth realise power of God and give chance to humans to restrict their sins.

```
       GLOBAL FATHERS
```

SECRETS ABOUT ABOVE MENTIONED PITRUUN (FATHERS OF globe & MOTHERs of living beings) are scriptured with physical forms & idols & stories. But, secrets regarding their move towards incarnation-return to Earth-blessings to children and their secret powers are ALL LOST because this YUGA IS KALIYUGA in KAALA CHAKRA.

DUE TO KALIYUGA ONLY OFFERINGS (WITHOUT KNOWING PURPOSE ARE PRACTICED). FOLLOWING ARE OFFERINGS to PITRU LOKA from various parts on Earth

1. sesame topped Appam(less sweet bread made of flour) - Indian
2. Bread and Brine - Jewish
3. Rye bread (dried) - German Christian
4. Kheer with rice flour and Milk - Muslim
5. Pitta bread with red grape wine  - Roman & European
6. Melon fruit - Catholic & American Christians
7. Coconut puffed maize roll - Islandic Asians & Africans
8. Lentil bread - Jains
9. Sour dark choclates - non followers of religion

Comment: You have not given a single reference from the Hindu scriptures! You have to back up every point with scriptural reference in this forum.